# What are alternatives to a double sanitary tee for back to back toilets?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, pipe

I'm remodeling two back to back bathrooms. None of the fixtures are staying in the same place so I'm essentially starting from scratch. After a lot of research I've put together a plan that looks right to me. However, looking back through the IPC, [706.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018P3/chapter-7-sanitary-drainage#IPC2018P3_Ch07_Sec706.3) says:

> Double sanitary tee patterns shall not receive the discharge of back-to-back water closets and fixtures or appliances with plumbing action discharge.

> Exception: Back-to-back water closets connections to double sanitary tees shall be permitted where the horizontal *developed length* between the outlet of the water closet and the connection to the double sanitary tee pattern is 18 inches or greater.

My toilets rough in at a standard 12 inches, so I believe that's saying I can't use the double tee for this instance.

Am I understanding that correctly? And if so, what's an alternative design?

Also, if anything else looks like it isn't to code, or there might be a better design, please let me know.

[image: back to back bathroom waste pipes]

Comment: I'm concerned with your vertical to horizontal transitions at both '5's. You can't use a sanitary-tee to transition from vertical to horizontal like that afaik.

Comment: @brhans thanks, you're right. I guess they could both be a combination wye & 8th bend or is there another fitting you'd recommend?

Comment: I had to refresh my memory with the IPC table - but it looks like either a 'straight' wye + 1/8 bend or a combo-wye by itself will do the job. The combo-wye is the one which typically looks like a sanitary-tee stretched out into a long-sweep, and doesn't need the extra 1/8 bend for a 90-degree transition..